# In LINQ to SQL, how do you determine what column elements is a sub-set of another column (i.e. Like-Sql statement)

Tags: linq-to-sql

Here is some code:

```
//all possible search terms of interest 
searchTerms = from s in dc.SearchTerms
              select s.term;

//all possible  results  
var results = from r in dc.Data
              select r.hyperlinks;
```

I want to perform an operation where I get all "r.hyperlinks" that contains s.term. 
It is something like r.hyperlinks.Contains(s.term). How can I do this?

Comment: P/S Feel free to modify this question if that makes it clearer.

Comment: @Phil: Don't worry we do ;)  May I suggest you spend a little time reading the Mark down documentation so that we don't have to modify your questions for you in future?

Comment: Hmmm looks like you are asking to get all r.hyperlinks that contains ANY of the search terms, isn't it? If this is it, I've misread your question at first...

Comment: @Bruno Reis, Yes. I want all r.hyperlinks that contains ANY of the search terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost as you wrote it in english:

```
var results = from r in dc.Data
              where searchTerms.Any(x => r.hyperlinks.Contains(x))
              select r.hyperlinks;
```

That's all!

You can put any condition you might come up inside a where clause. Actually, you can put whatever returns a `boolean`.

Comment: Not everything that can be done in LINQ to objects can be done in LINQ to SQL.  Ultimately the expression needs to be transformed to T-SQL.  @Phil: Bombed? It would help if you include in your question the error you are getting.

Comment: Updated to reflect OP's comment on his question.

Comment: By "bombed" I mean there was a syntax error. The error I get is: 

"Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator."

Answer (score 0):

Local sequences cannot be used in many LinqToSql operators.  But your original question didn't require a local sequence.

```
var results =
    from r in dc.Data
    where dc.SearchTerms.Any(s => r.hyperlinks.Contains(s.Term))
    select r.hyperlinks;
```

Comment: Here is the error I get: "Only arguments that can be evaluated on the client are supported for the String.Contains method." Do not worry about it. I will just use stored proc.